# Why GRB format for programmable LEDs?

Tags: led, rgb, grb

Why manufacturers use GRB(Green, Red, Blue) format for "RGB programmable LEDs" instead classic RGB format?

Eg. [IN-PI55TAT](https://hr.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Inolux/IN-PI55TATPRPGPB/?qs=mAH9sUMRCttUWI%2F2sR%2FcZg%3D%3D) RGB LED 4 pin

From the bottom of Page 6 on the datasheet:

[image]

Is this choice based on hardware simplicity or with by engineers?

Comment: The [datasheet](http://www.inolux-corp.com/datasheet/SMDLED/Addressable%20LED/IN-PI55TAT(X)R(X)G(X)B_v1.3.pdf) has no mention of GRB and specifically uses the term RGB. Are you asking about the sequence of the 24-bit data format? If so, it's certainly not clear from your question. Read it out loud to yourself so you hear what we read.

Comment: @Transistor It is on page 6 in linked datasheet.

Comment: Note that you didn't answer my question. I've done a text search of the document and there is no mention of GRB.

Comment: you will have to ask the manufacturer ... your question is like asking `why do some people wash their face first, and then brush their teeth?`

Comment: A computer doesn't care about which LED comes first. RGB is just the way that acronym is communicated. The order of the register was determined by some engineer, and it doesn't really matter which color comes first.

Comment: Doc was probably written by a British engineer.   I mean, they drive on the wrong side of the road and all, so why not change up RGB order    ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The physical arrangement of the LED dice is in that order (photo from Pololu), which would represent the physical arrangement of the shift register on the chip.

[image]

As to why you'd want to put the red die in the center of the lens, I would speculate that it is because red is typically the weakest of the three LEDs in terms of light output per mA so placing it near the center gives it a better chance.

Note: this is just speculation, but it holds together. Note also that the chip version of the [WS2811](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2811.pdf) is shown with RGB data arranged in that order, so the chip designers had the notion to connect them to LEDs in that order.

The LED manufacturers (typically distinct firms) decided to scramble the outputs for some reason of their own.